# emberjs: add routes after app initialize()

Tags: ember.js, router

i run into the following problem when building a router based app with emberjs. My app is simplified structured as following:

```
var App = Em.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationController   = Em.Controller.extend({});

App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({

    template    : Em.Handlebars.compile('APPLICATION TEMPLATE')

});


App.RootState   = Em.Route.extend({

    index   : Em.Route.extend({
        route   : "/"
    })

})

App.Router  = Em.Router.extend({

    root    : App.RootState

});

    // initialize the app here
App.initialize();

// extend the RootState from anywhere. eg. from a plugged widget 
App.RootState.reopen({

    login   : Em.Route.extend({
        route   : "/state1"
    })

});

//App.initialize(); //init the app a second time forces unexpected behaviour 

App.RootState.reopen({

    alarms  : Em.Route.extend({
        route   : "/state2"
    })

});

//App.initialize();
```

Like my app demonstrates, i try to extend the router with new routes at runtime. I know that there exists another thread with similar question exists, but the discussed example do not work for me. 
How can i extend my router at runtime with additional routes, without calling initialize() after every ...reopen({ }).

The background for doing this is to decide at runtime how the application is look like, for example to plug in different wigets with their own routes.

Regards,
T

Comment: Could you describe what's kind of problem happen with your code ? Are the new defined routes accessible ? Are the controllers not available ?

Comment: okay. my problem is the following. After reopen RootState i am not able to access the new properties aka route that i want to add to the router. i have to call the initialize - method again to get access. But by doing that, the App gets in the init-state twice, so that eg. my applicationView is drawn twice. Can you follow my execution?

Comment: I don't know exactly how works the reopen, but I think when you call reopen on a class, the new behavior is available on new instances, but not on instances already defined. So at initialization time, the entire router is defined. Unfortunately, I think what you're trying to do (define new routes at runtime) is not possible...

Comment: As per [documentation](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_reopening-classes-and-instances), it seems like you should be using `reopenClass` and not `reopen` as shown is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269372/ember-js-how-does-reopenclass-work)